# 3D band structure study using a 1D Kronig-Penney model

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory

My question is wether one can use a one dimensional simulation for the Kronig Penney model in order to study a 3 dimensional crystal. I have seen that the problem of a 3 dimensional crystal can’t be reduced in a trivial way to three 1D problems. For example, supposing a cubic well potential, it can be factorized as a product of 3 square well potentials, i.e., $V(x,y,z)=V(x)V(y)V(z)$, but this doesn’t help you separate variables in the Schrödinger equation and thus reduce the problem to three unidimensional ones (In order to do it you would need $V(x,y,z)=V(x)+V(y)+V(z)$).
I have heard that this can be done in a non-trivial way (studying a 3D crystal from unidimensional models), but I can’t find anything related on the Internet. Any help and resources related to my question are well received.

Comment: You can easily study a cubic system by product of 3 square well potentials, but there is no point to such a thing. It will not bring any useful physical insights not already found in the 1D case, and if a problem is worth working in 3D for, it is worth getting better approximations for.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself good enough @naturallyInconsistent, my goal is to study a 3D crystal through unidimensional systems: How to extrapolate unidimensional results to 3D